# Como executar um script em python no Notepadqq?

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

[image]

quando aperto em "RUN" aparece essa janela

Answer (score 0):

Na imagem que vc colocou na pergunta tem um campo para vc digitar um comando, digite o comando para rodar o script atual, no meu caso eu digitaria:

```
/usr/bin/python %path%
```

Qdo vc confirmar será solicitado um nome curto para o comando, de o nome que voce quiser, por exemplo: "Run Python".

Talvez funcione tambem simplesmente `python %path%` ao inves de colocar o caminnho completo do python, para descobrir os possíveis caminhos do python em seu sistema, digite, na linha de comando:

```
$ whereis python
```

Saida (no meu ambiente):

```
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.6m-config /usr/bin/python ....
```

Depois que vc fizer os procedimentos acima, surgirá uma nova opção no menu Run do notepadqq, que é um "shortcut" para rodar o arquivo corrente em python (com o nome q vc colocou).